# Identify IE9/IE10 using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, browser-detection

I have a jQuery code which is working fine for Chrome/Mozilla but not IE.

```
if ($("html").hasClass("ie")) {
    $(function(){
        $('.green-column, .red-column, .grey-column').click(function() { 
             alert ($(this).attr("data-type"));           
        });
    });
}
else {
 $(function(){
        $('.green-column, .red-column, .grey-column').click(function() { 
         $("<div title='Selected Task is:'>" + $(this).attr("data-type") + "</div>").dialog({ 
             modal: true,
             resizable: false,
             buttons: [
                {
                   text: "OK", 
                   click: function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" ); }
                }
             ]
         });
    });
});
}
</script> 
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html lang="en-us" class="ie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html lang="en-us" class="ie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en-us" class="ie"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

So I plan to use an alert for IE9/IE10 but I am not able to differentiate between the browsers. Can anyone tell me how to identify IE9/IE10 in jQuery/HTML?

Comment: It's not good to differ between browsers nor to deny access for a browser. JQuery should work with IE 9 & 10, so maybe there is a failure in your HTML or CSS code. Try to fix this and don't use browser sniffing.

Comment: If you have a render bug which only occurs in a certain browser and the only way to fix it, is to change a slideUp() to a hide(). Only for certain browsers...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Can be achieved without using libraries or conditional compilation:

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
    alert("IE9 or greater");
}

if (window.requestAnimationFrame) {
    alert("IE10 or greater");
}
```

Comment: Kinda offtopic comment but you can use these 2 conditions to check specifically for `IE9`: `if(document.addEventListener && !window.requestAnimationFrame) { alert("IE9") }`

Answer (score 7):

Just do like this

```
if ($.browser.msie  && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) > 8) {
  alert('IE9 or IE10'); 
} else {
  alert('Non IE9 or IE10');
}
```

This should work for jQuery version under 1.9. If you use 1.9+, read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545023/jquery-1-9-browser-detection) or consider using [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/).

Comment: This only work in versions of jquery prior to 1.9. The $.browser was removed from versions > 1.9.

Answer (score 6):

The only reliable way to detect the currently active IE version (possibly emulated) is to combine [conditional compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kx09ct1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and a [`document.documentMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc196988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) check.

Conditional compilation is optional, but it allows you to never run the IE-detection script for non-IE browsers.

For example:

```
if (/*@cc_on !@*/false && (
       document.documentMode === 9 || document.documentMode === 10)
   ) {
    // IE 9 or 10 (not 8 or 11!)
    document.documentElement.className += ' ie9 ie10';
}
```

The previous code is not safe against minifiers. If you're going to minify your code, put the conditional compilation stuff in a string, and `eval` it:

```
if (eval('/*@cc_on !@*/false') && ( ... )) { ... }
```

Comment: I was previously unaware of conditional JS compilation in IE.

Entire subject is explained in detail @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/8ka90k2e(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: @ElanHasson Conditional compilation has been removed from IE11. `document.documentMode` is still there though.

Comment: heh, not that big a deal.. by then we'll have better standards cross-browser and it'll be legacy (Pre-IE10 and Post IE10) :)

Answer (score 2):

Older jQuery versions before 1.9 offered `$.browser` to get this. Now jQuery wants you to check for functions instead via `$.support`.

A pretty good alternative is modernizr (http://modernizr.com/). Modernizr adds classes to your root element like `msie` or `ie9` or `webkit` or `touch` and so on.

So you can easily check:

```
if ($('html').hasClass('ie9')) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: What about just doing "if ($('html').is('.ie6, .ie7'))"?  Is there any drawbacks or issues with using something as simple as that with jquery?  Does that also require Modernizer?

Comment: You wouldn't have classes like 'ie7' using only jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question. but in case you haven’t found an answer.

[Show a message if the browser is not internet explorer 9 or greater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739655/show-a-message-if-the-browser-is-not-internet-explorer-9-or-greater?lq=1)

```
browser={};
if (/(chrome\/[0-9]{2})/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    browser.agent = navigator.userAgent.match(/(chrome\/[0-9]{2})/i)[0].split("/")[0];
    browser.version  = parseInt(navigator.userAgent.match(/(chrome\/[0-9]{2})/i)[0].split("/")[1]);
} else if (/(firefox\/[0-9]{2})/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    browser.agent = navigator.userAgent.match(/(firefox\/[0-9]{2})/i)[0].split("/")[0];
    browser.version  = parseInt(navigator.userAgent.match(/(firefox\/[0-9]{2})/i)[0].split("/")[1]);
} else if (/(MSIE\ [0-9]{1})/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    browser.agent = navigator.userAgent.match(/(MSIE\ [0-9]{1})/i)[0].split(" ")[0];
    browser.version  = parseInt(navigator.userAgent.match(/(MSIE\ [0-9]{1})/i)[0].split(" ")[1]);
} else if (/(Opera\/[0-9]{1})/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    browser.agent = navigator.userAgent.match(/(Opera\/[0-9]{1})/i)[0].split("/")[0];
    browser.version  = parseInt(navigator.userAgent.match(/(Opera\/[0-9]{1})/i)[0].split("/")[1]);
} else if (/(Trident\/[7]{1})/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    browser.agent = "MSIE";
    browser.version  = 11;
} else {
    browser.agent = false;
    browser.version  = false;
}

if (/(Windows\ NT\ [0-9]{1}\.[0-9]{1})/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    browser.os = "Windows";
    switch(parseFloat(navigator.userAgent.match(/(Windows\ NT\ [0-9]{1}\.[0-9]{1})/)[0].split(" ")[2])) {
    case 6.0:
        browser.osversion = "Vista";
        break;
    case 6.1:
        browser.osversion = "7";
        break;
    case 6.2:
        browser.osversion = "8";
        break;
    default:
        browser.osversion = false;
    }
} else if (/(OS\ X\ [0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{1})/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    browser.os = "OS X";
    browser.osversion = navigator.userAgent.match(/(OS\ X\ [0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{1})/)[0].split(" ")[2];
} else if (/(Linux)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    browser.os = "Linux";
    browser.osversion = false;
}
```