# Blank page with "browser not supported" for IE 7, 8, 9, 10

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I've read many questions and answers such as [Check for IE 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135814/check-for-ie-10), [How do I target only Internet Explorer 10 for certain situations like Internet Explorer-specific CSS or Internet Explorer-specific JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900311/how-do-i-target-only-internet-explorer-10-for-certain-situations-like-internet-e), [How do I detect IE10 using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16366907/how-do-i-detect-ie10-using-javascript), [Best way to check for IE less than 9 in JavaScript without library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574842/best-way-to-check-for-ie-less-than-9-in-javascript-without-library), and above all [Detect IE version (prior to v9) in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964966/detect-ie-version-prior-to-v9-in-javascript), etc.

Most of them use Javascript, jQuery (but 1.9+ doesn't seem to support $.browser anymore...), and adding a special class to `<html>` when IE <= 10 is used, allowing specific handling with CSS.

I want to do something simpler : **have the HTML page display "Browser not supported" only and nothing else when IE <= 10 is used** (i.e. the rest of the page should be hidden).

What's the recommended way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want only display it when the version of I.E below I.E 10 right? I've thinking something like this :

```
<!--[if lt IE 10]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.location.href="asd.html";
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

this method is called "conditional comment" which only run things inside the comment tag only when it meet the I.E version condition. You can change content/rule inside that tag the way you want. I **Recommend** you to use this **'conditional comment' method.** you can find more about that in [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment)

and i've attach some simple example rule to redirect the page to another page, and you can write your 'browser not suported' message in that another page.

note: put that conditional comment inside 'head' tag.

- i hope this help.

Comment: Thanks! But this doesn't seem to detect IE 10 correctly.

Comment: what? are you also not gonna support IE 10 too?? that browser is not too old to abandon i think..

Comment: well, if that te case,..just try change <!--[if lt IE 10]> into <!--[if lte IE 10]> .

Comment: I don't really understand why this answer was the chosen one when i gave the same answer... I guess that giving examples isn't enough. You actually have to do everything.

Comment: IE10 needed <!--[if !IE]><!-->

<!--<![endif]--> combined with @cc_on I thought?

Like so: <script>if(/*@cc_on!@*/false){location.href="no-ie.html";}</script>