# Checking IE browser version using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have certain functionality that I want to run only if respondent is using IE 9 or above, please suggest how can I do this in jQuery.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [check if user is using IE with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999388/check-if-user-is-using-ie-with-jquery)

Comment: @areim Please explain with code

Comment: or you can read http://www.sitepoint.com/check-ie-version/

Comment: another duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657614/identify-ie9-ie10-using-jquery

Answer (score 2):

the feature to detect browser info through jquery by using `$.browser` has been deprecated(in version 1.3) and removed(in version 1.9) .However you can simply use html to do this.

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //script for ie9 and above
  </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Good practice is to use [feature detection instead of browser detection](https://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/feature-browser-detection/)

In this way you look if the browser can handle the specific case, and then use that functionality