# jquery datatables FixedColumns not defined

Tags: jquery, sorting, jquery-plugins, datatables

I'm attempting to use the [jquery datatables plugin](http://www.datatables.net/) and following [the FixedColumns example](http://www.datatables.net/extras/fixedcolumns/)
but I'm getting the error `Error: ReferenceError: FixedColumns is not defined Line: 64`. I'm trying to make the leftmost column fixed so while you scroll horizontally you can still see the first column.

I have set up an [example in jsbin](http://jsbin.com/uziwin/2/edit) that shows the error. Is FixedColumns a separate plugin to download? I couldn't find it if it is. Anyone able to explain why my code isn't working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That [FixedColumns plugin](http://www.datatables.net/extras/fixedcolumns/) needs some update, browser console currently reports

`TypeError: $.browser is undefined @ http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedColumns/media/js/FixedColumns.js:99`;

$.browser was removed from jQuery 1.9, so you can either use jQuery 1.8.3 instead: http://jsbin.com/uziwin/4/edit

or [add the browser detection back to jQuery 1.9+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545023/jquery-1-9-browser-detection) with some additional plugin: https://github.com/mattberg/jquery-browser ; http://jsbin.com/uziwin/11/edit