# DataTables FixedColumn Destroy not working

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I've got a strange issue with DataTables and destroy. I am using version 1.10.3 (but also tried 1.10.7) and fixedColumns Plugin (3.0). When I want to destroy the table I get an error in the plugin:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fn is not a function

My init looks like this:

```
fulltable = $('#auditplan_table_fs').dataTable();
```

and the destroy

```
fulltable.fnDestroy();
```

but I've also tried to initalize via `.DataTable()` and destroy via `.api().destroy()` or `.destroy()` which leads to the same result. Any possible solution would be appreciated.

UPDATE:
As it seems it isn't a problem with FixedColumns, here is some more information. I'm calling the dataTable in an ajax `success` like this:

```
$('#auditplan_table_fs').append(responseData.findinglist.html);
          fulltable = $('#auditplan_table_fs').dataTable({
            scrollY: newheight,
            scrollX: true,
            scrollCollapse: true,
            "bSort": false,
            paging: false
});
new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns(fulltable);
```

In a document change function (when I select some values from a dropdown) I try to destroy the table like I posted before and then call the ajax function again.

The `fulltable` variable is defined in my document ready, the assignment happens, as already told, in my `success` function. When I print out the variable right before the destroy, everything seems to be fine.

UPDATE: It seems to be a bug in fixedColumns itself. I found out I am using 3.0.0 and the newest version is 3.0.4. With this one, I passed the first error and come up with a new one. I now get stuck in Line 1107:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'anCells' of undefined

I suppose it has to do something with my init in an ajax call.

LAST UPDATE: Ok, I was to fast. It was only a caching problem. With the new version, everything is working fine.

Comment: Both methods should work right away, `dataTable()` -> `fnDestroy()` and `DataTable()` -> `destroy()` http://jsfiddle.net/4toLj9yn/412 and here http://jsfiddle.net/4toLj9yn/413 (both with 1.10.7 and FixedColumns)

Comment: funny thing. Then I have to look for the problem elsewhere

Comment: Try post your code. The problem is as you said most certainly elsewhere around your use of dataTables.

Answer (score 0):

> If you do:
>
> 1. jQuery
> 2. DataTables
> 3. jQuery

The second jQuery will overwrite the first one (which has DataTables attached to it). Thus, you would end up with a jQuery object that doesn't have `DataTables` available.

Bit frustrating that jQuery doesn't give an error about being loaded twice as it bites a lot of people

**[Reference](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/8187/weird-error-fnadddata-is-not-a-function)**

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, because when I remove the fixedColumns call, destroy works as expected.

Comment: is fixedColumns call is working ?Do you have any warnings in console after calling it?@Andi

Comment: fixedColumns itself is working fine until I call the destroy command. After that I get a "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fn is not a function" in the fixedColumns script on line 552 somwhere in _fnConstruct

Comment: can i know version of JQuery you are using?@Andi

Comment: I am at Version 1.11.0

Comment: Then it is a problem with version you have follow this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845257/jquery-datatables-fixedcolumns-not-defined/16947004#16947004 @Andi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80865/discussion-between-anr-upgraded-version-and-andi).

Comment: I don't think this is a problem anymore in the current Plugin version as this discussion is 2 years old.

Comment: can i have fiddle of your code for more observation@Andi